# How to use indexOf in Java

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, rss

I'm trying to parse a title from the following piece of html:

```
"Website (Newton) at datanucleus.org">Website</a></div>
```

I am using `indexOf` as such:  `strLine.indexOf("\">Website")`

and I want to know how to search for the first SPACE occurring BEFORE the link.  So I want to capture everything between " " and "">Website<"

i.e. `datanucleus.org`

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Depending on how complex your situation in, you may want to consider using a proper HTML parser.  Anyway, learn the string functions better.  This is a relatively simple thing to do.  Just calculate what indexes to pass substring.

Comment: Strongly agreed with @Corbin about using an HTML parser, but if you're going to stick with the basics, you should start thinking about using a regex.

Comment: roger that, I'll look into it.  Wasn't sure if this was simple or one of those tricky things.

Comment: Just be aware that if you try to do string matching without doing a full parse using a real parser, you're sometimes going to get it wrong - for example you might match content that has been commented out, or fail to match content if the attributes are in single quotes rather than double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
int end = strLine.indexOf("\">Website");
int start = strLine.lastIndexOf(" ", end);
```

From the docs of `lastIndexOf`:

> Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward starting at the specified index.

There is also a version of `lastIndexOf` that takes a `char` instead of a string; that might be more efficient in this particular case (but I haven't checked):

```
int start = strLine.lastIndexOf(' ', end);
```

For more complex things you could also consider looking into the java.util.regex package.

Comment: That will search for the last space that occurs _after_ `end`. OP wants the last space _before_ `end`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: are you sure? I tested it (see: http://pastebin.com/2qvH5bfQ) and i get this output: end: 36; start: 20

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think this should work.  I found this answer myself after a quick search :).  Ted, I think you are mistaken, but I will try.

Comment: My mistake. It does indeed search backwards from the indicated index.

Answer (score 1):

If you have int idx = str.indexOf("\">Website"), you can use String.lastIndexOf(" ", idx); to get the previous space. Then use substring!

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression approach will probably be the most efficient. However, you can do this with a combination of `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` and `substring` calls.

```
int end = strLine.indexOf("\"Website");
int blank = strLine.substring(0, end).lastIndexOf(' ');
String interestingStuff = strLine.substring(blank + 1, end);
```